# How to silently ignore datetime parse failures?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvpBX.jpg) is a screenshot of my error.

The Trans_Imp_Date values are failing to be converted to pandas datetime format (yyyy-mm-dd). However the process is working fine for the other two columns.

I want it so that if the convert-to-datetime process fails for a specific row, pandas ignores that specific row and output the input without conversion (as per the errors = 'ignore' flag), and then continue converting the rest of the rows. How can I make that happen?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't get Pandas to ignore bad cells on failure. You need to check for them and remove or replace them.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try and work around it then. I thought errors  = ignore was supposed to ignore bad cells: errors : {‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’

If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input

Answer (score 0):

Use [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html).

If you modify values in `df_p` by function [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`p_junjul_trans_orig`), and that Pandas does warning.

```
cols = ['Imp_Trans_Date','Trans_Imp_Date','Imposition_Date_of_Hearing']
df_p = p_junjul_trans_orig[cols].copy()
```

EDIT:

It seems some problem with data, e.g. traling whitespaces, what is possible check by:

```
print (df_p['Trans_Imp_Date'].head().tolist())
```

Comment: At this stage I'm not trying to modify the original data (p_junjul_trans_orig), I would like to keep that as it is. I want to modify the column 'Trans_Imp_Date' in 'df_p'.

Comment: @Falc - hmmm, so it failed only for one column? And if comment it, no error? There should be problem with [chained assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20644369/2901002), but I guess it should raise warning for each `to_datetime`

Comment: Yep its failing for that one column, all the output I have is included in the screenshot.

Comment: @Falc - I now understand, check edited answer. Btw, why dont use `errors='coerce'` parameter for convert not parseable values to `NaT` ?

Comment: print (df_p['Trans_Imp_Date'].head().tolist()) gives the output:

['25/06/2018', '25/06/2018', '20/06/2018', '20/06/2018', '20/06/2018']. I don't want to use coerce because then I lose the value of what was there before.

Comment: @Falc - It looks nice, are data confidental? If not, is possible share `df_p.to_csv(file)` ? E.g. by gdocs, dropbox, similar? Or sent it to my email from my profile?

Comment: Sorry its confidential. I think coerce is a good option though, I can use that to pick up cells which are broken. thanks for your helpT